# Interpretation of the Lebesgue measure $dV(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to find a meaning (probably a geometric meaning) for the notation used for the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{C}^n$.
Is there a way to clarify the meaning of this quantity in terms of $2n$-dimensional volume.

Comment: $dV(z_1,\dots,z_n) = dx_1 dy_1 \dots dx_n dy_n$?

Comment: @Mason, right, but what does $dV$ mean here?

Comment: It's just notation, like the $dx$ in the 1d integral, or the $d\mu$ when integrating against a measure.